# Print screen in Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-ace, screenshots

How to Take Print Screen in Samsung Galaxy ace Duos? Can please some body help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Android screenshot method is `Power Button` + `Home Button`

Comment: Ok Where can i see that Image?

Comment: Look at your Gallery,there will be a folder named Screeshots

Comment: after Pressing Power Button + Home Button i checked but it doesn't work

Comment: It took me a while to get the hang of it properly. Press and hold power button then press home button (On my HTC I need to hold home for approx 0.5 seconds for it to work). Also don't hold power too long before pressing home else you will just get the power menu appear.

Comment: what button first i should press?

Comment: Power first, then Home